# Is it sufficient to use where in twice on a table with a composite PK?

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2000

I have a query

```
SELECT * 
FROM table1
WHERE
documentId in
(
   --select items from a second table where a third column happens to be null
   select documentId from table2 t2 inner join table1 t1
   on t1.documentId = t2.documentId and t1.itemId = t2.ItemId
   WHERE t1.someOtherColumn is null
)
and itemId in
(
   --similar query as above, just selecting itemId now
   select itemId from table2 t2 inner join table1 t1
   on t1.documentId = t2.documentId and t1.itemId = t2.ItemId
   WHERE t1.someOtherColumn is null
)
order by 1
```

Given that table1 has composite PK = documentId + itemId, is this sufficient to select only values from table1 that are unique?  My fear is that a situation may occur where documentId exists and itemId exists, but since they are not looked at together then incorrect selections can be made.

For example,

Let's assume that there exists a value

> documentId = 1 and itemId = 1.

Let's assume there is no composite key

> documentId = 1 and itemId = 1.

I do not want composite key

> [documentId = 1 and itemId = 3]

to be included.

I also do not want composite key

> [documentId = 2 and itemId = 1]

to be included.

If there were a composite key added later (it's not there now)

> [documentId = 1 and itemId = 1]

then it should be included.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This would do the same without having to use a join nor two `IN`s

```
SELECT *
FROM table1
WHERE exists
(
    SELECT 1
    FROM table2
    WHERE someOtherColumn is null
        AND table1.documentId = table2.documentId
        AND table1.itemId = table2.ItemId
)
ORDER BY 1
```

Answer (score 5):

You are correct assuming that it may lead to erroneous results. You could use this:

```
SELECT table1.* 
FROM table1
WHERE someOtherColumn IS NULL
  AND (documentId, itemId ) IN
   (
   SELECT documentId, itemId 
   FROM table2 t2                  --- no need for table1 again here 
   )
ORDER BY 1
```

---

Update: I think the above does not wotk in SQL-Server, only in Postgres (and Oracle?). Anyway, this should work in most systems:

```
SELECT table1.* 
FROM table1
WHERE someOtherColumn IS NULL
  AND EXISTS
   (
   SELECT documentId, itemId FROM table2 t2     
   WHERE table2.documentId = table1.documentId
     AND table2.itemId = table1.itemId
   )
ORDER BY 1
```

Comment: This looks very promising. I'm unable to get it to work.  Error `Incorrect syntax near ','` referring to the `where (documentId,`

Comment: It's `WHERE t1.someOtherColumn` so `t1` is required.  Sorry for not making that clear in the original post.  I updated it.

Comment: "I think the [first query] does not wotk in SQL-Server" -- correct but it is an oft asked for feature that can be voted for [here](http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/299231/add-support-for-ansi-standard-row-value-constructors).

Answer (score 2):

how about this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table1,
(
   select documentId, itemid from table2 t2 inner join table1 t1
   on t1.documentId = t2.documentId and t1.itemId = t2.ItemId
   WHERE someOtherColumn is null
) t
WHERE
table1.documentId = t.documentid
and table1.itemId = t.itemid
order by 1
```

Comment: This is a really bad solution, sorry for saying. If there is not a 1 to 1 relation between table1 and table2, you will get alot of extra rows. Example: if there are 3 rows in table1 joined with 1 row in table2, you get 3 rows for the subquery resulting in 9 rows for the whole query.

Comment: i think a simple DISTINCT would mitigate that..  the OP didn't specify anything about the select list.

Comment: You should never use distinct to compensate for a badly written query.